# How to get Shipment Id in order page View.php

Tags: magento-1.9, sales-order, shipment, ce-1.9.2.3

I am using the partial shipment case for multiple shipments and multiple tracking number against one order. For this i have added the new button (Leopard TN) on order view page. Actually when we click on this button its will send the shipment id and order id to the external page by using query string.

I have the order id in the external page by using the below code but i also need to get the shipment id in the next page.

```
$url = "http://www.exportleftovers.co/leopardmagento/api_call_get.php?order_id={$order->getId()}";
$this->_addButton('get_review_payment_update', array(
    'label'     => Mage::helper('sales')->__('Leopard TN'),
    'onclick' => "window.open('".$url."')"

));
```

Is anyone know how can i get the shipment id and send to the external page?

Comment: Which version you try?

Comment: magento 1.9.2.3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have `$order` object then you can easily find out shipping id. Here is an example:

```
if (!$order->canShip()) {
    foreach ($order->getShipmentsCollection() as $shipment) {
        $shipmentId = $shipment->getId();
    }
}
```

OR

```
if (!$order->canShip()) {
    $shipment = $order->getShipmentsCollection()->getFirstItem();
    $shipmentId = $shipment->getId();
}
```

Below Code is working fine:

```
foreach ($order->getShipmentsCollection() as $shipment) {
    $shipmentId = $shipment->getId();

    $url = "http://www.example.co/filename.php?order_id={$order->getId()}&shipment_id=$shipmentId";

    $this->_addButton('get_review_payment_update', array(
        'label' => Mage::helper('sales')->__('Leopard TN'),
        'onclick' => "window.open('" . $url . "')"

    ));

}
```

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Hi, i try both but i am unable to get the shipment id, i also mention code that i am using in view.php to get the order id. can you please explain how can i get the shipment id?

Comment: you can get shipment_id if you created any shipment.

Comment: yes i create the shipment but didn't get any shipment id, basically i am working with partial shipment concept.

Comment: I think you try this from 'Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Sales_Order_View' ? It's working for me. Could you show your code?

Comment: i edit you answer for final solution. thanks for help.